# What are two statements $A$ and $B$ such that $A \oplus B \Rightarrow A \land \neg B$?

Tags: logic

I'm looking for two simple statements $A$ and $B$ that satisfy the following.

You can't say anything about the truth of either $A$ or $B$ beforehand, but given that exactly one of them is true, $A$ will be the true one (and $B$ the false).

In logical notation, I want to find statements satisfying $A \oplus B \Rightarrow A \land \neg B$.

Can 2 such statements even be constructed?

Comment: You just want $B \to A$ to be true, then...  Pick your favorite example?

Comment: $A=B=1+1=2$ is an example.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Your answer seems to be correct. (example: "X is a quadrilateral" and "X is a square"). I'm not sure why though? As in, how might I have derived that fact?

Comment: It's just the disjunctive syllogism: $$P \lor Q, \lnot P \vdash Q$$ where $P$ is $(\lnot A) \land B$ and $Q$ is $A \land (\lnot B)$.  You are asking how to find statements such that $(P \lor Q) \to Q$ is true.  Then the easiest way is to assume $$\lnot P \equiv \lnot( (\lnot A) \land B) \equiv A \lor (\lnot B) \equiv B \to A$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring It would be worth placing these comments in an answer for future readers.